# setTimeout and clearTimeout in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a greeting UI that fades out before displaying main content.The desired effect can be found [HERE](http://help.apple.com/macOS/high-sierra/macbook-pro-13/?lang=en&cases=kIFAGHvXTAepRptQXiXe5w,N0bfKOvERSiAp06mHOcgOQ#outro)

When a certain scroll input, say 100px from the top, is reached

1. Greeting appears for 5seconds and fades out
2. Main content waits until greeting fades out and gets displayed.

I achieved this effect with setTimeout but I now want to know how to set clearTimeout properly.

Here is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener(
      "wheel",
      () => requestAnimationFrame(this.handleScroll.bind(this)),
      false
    );
  }

handleScroll(e){  
    const scrolltop = window.scrollY; 
    scrolltop > 120 ? this.showGreeting().bind(this):null
  }

showGreeting(){
    this.setState({
      greetingDisplay:true,
    })
    const timer = setTimeout(this.showContent.bind(this),5000);
  } 

showContent(){

    this.setState({
      greetingDisplay:false,
      contentDisplay:1,
   })
  //How do I clear the timer here? 
}
```

- [Here](https://codepen.io/semosem/pen/PQgoqJ?editors=0011) is my attempt, Codepen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `showGreeting`,you are setting timeout and storing it in `local const` varibale.Instead bind it to component instance i.e. `this`.

```
constructor(){
     this.timer = null;
      //............rest
  }

showGreeting(){
    this.setState({
      greetingDisplay:true,
    })
    this.timer=setTimeout(this.showContent.bind(this),3000);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
```

When `showContent` is called state is updated which will trigger `render` and then `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle.

In the `componentDidUpdate`, use `this.timer` to clear timeout.

```
componentDidUpdate{
   clearTimeout(this.timer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use ES6 arrow functions without side effects like this:

```
showContent = () => {
   this.setState({
      greetingDisplay:false,
      contentDisplay:1,
   }); 
}

showGreeting = () => {
    this.setState({
      greetingDisplay:true,
    });
    setTimeout( () => this.showContent, 3000 );
}
```